# JFace Dialog maximize programmatically

Tags: java, dialog, swt, jface

I am currently trying to maximize a JFace `Dialog` programmatically.
Usually calling `setMaximized(true)` on the `parentShell` of the `Dialog` would be sufficient to achieve this.

However, it does not work for my `Dialog`. Maximizing it manually using the window buttons works.

Does anybody have an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do following:

```
Rectangle bounds = parentShell.getDisplay().getClientArea();
myDialog.setBounds(bounds);
parentShell.setMaximized(true);
```

**UPD:** But this approach is not fairly true as this code breaks previous size of you dialog.
Following approach seems to work better:

```
parentShell.pack();
parentShell.setMaximized(true);
```

Comment: I switched over to a simple `Composite`, but your solution did work. Thanks.